# Does reSELECT [tblmytable] clear a filter?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I'm converting a Foxpro app and I'm having a bit of trouble with database table referencing/selection. I'm not in a position to run the Foxpro code as I only have code dumps with which to work. If someone could help me understand what is happening here I'd be most grateful. Yes... I searched.

```
SELECT tblMyTable
Set Filter To Inlist(cbid,123)
SELECT tblMyTable
```

- Does the second Select simply reselect tblMyTable and clear the filter?
- If not is a second instance being opened so you have one that’s filtered and one that isn’t?
- If so how do I reference each instance since they have no names? Automatically 1 and 2?

Lastly if I’ve got it completely wrong just give me a small clue and I’m on it. Thank you!

Comment: As I understand it, the first select is used to bring the table upon which the filter will be applied into scope. Basically, it assures that the `SET FILTER` command applies to `tblMyTable`. The second select is used to refresh the view. Presumably the table is used as a source to some type of control. That select would refresh the view. It does not open a second instance.

Comment: It's a refresh! For some reason I though Foxpro code sat directly on top of the database so there were no real "datasets" and you were always looking at "live" data. @user3561813 you have not only answered my question but you've changed my entire perspective of Foxpro code and Foxpro data. Thank you!

Comment: As the code is described, you are looking at live data. (Note: you could also be looking at a cursor that is built from a live data table, although that's not what I think is happening her). Nonetheless, setting the filter applies a filter to the live data, but doesn't actually update the view. The second select does that.

Comment: So what is "the view"? Is it a dataset that's created when you apply the filter to the live data? How is it referenced? Or maybe the created view is just automatically referenced if you run statements after applying the filter? Thank you and sorry... I'm new to all this Foxpro stuff.

Comment: When I say view, I'm referring to whichever UI element displays the table to the user (presuming that there is one). In many cases there might be a grid that uses the underlying table as its record source. Foxpro also allows the user to just show a view of the table. Hints might be found somewhere else in the source code. If you need to figure certain parts out, post them and we can try to work through it.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are being misguided.

Second select has no special meaning. That line is not needed at all, but wouldn't do an harm either.

If it were a view, then 'refreshing' a view is done by using Requery(), not by doing another 1 or more selects.

In fact, 'set filter' is on the list of (almost all VFP developers') "never to use commands" , exceptions like this might happen unfortunately.

If you are doing a conversion by only using code dumps and no VFP environment at all, then your task should be extremely hard. I would instead prefer a rewrite from scratch. That would be faster even for seasoned VFP developers.

Comment: Thank you Cetin Basoz. As a .Net/SQL developer I'm having a hard time with this data environment stuff. In the method I'm reviewing "SELECT mytable" is used at least 6 times. I don't know how you can limited data without a filter. I don't know why you'd have to refresh a view as SQL view never needs "refreshing" it's just a filter on live data. I also don't know why this Foxpro programmer writes her subqueries out to text files and then reads them back in. I'm not expecting you to answer all those questions but this is what I'm faced with so I'm doing my best. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GunnerFan420, besides VFP, I am also a C#\MS SQL (postgreSQL, sqlite ...) guy too. MS SQL Server Views in fact needs refreshing in .Net too. Here refresh means "fetch" current data. If you think about it, views are supposed to be "windows" to live data, not the live data itself. If you check behind the scenes, in say SQL Server too, it is just an SQL definition and not the data itself. With a view calling ReQuery(), executes the view's SQL definition again to refresh data. In C# too, you do it like that. I don't know your code where she writes subqueries to text files and reads back in.

Comment: @GunnerFan420, it might be she didn't know how to do that or it might be an ingenious way to workaround something, that could be perfectly valid in the days that her code written. And BTW, you can simply limit the data with an SQL or if you like to use xBase instead "Set range" is one of the ways to use, but not "set filter". Avoid "set filter".

Comment: Yes that is my perspective that views don't contain data so there is no data to refresh.  I'm sure you know what I mean. I can refresh a dataadapter or dataset that may use a view to get the data but I'm no refreshing the view itself. I have no doubt it's just terminology but it still gets confusing. Thank you for taking the time to explain things for me. I'm very grateful.

Comment: Oh yes it is terminology. VFP users, generally use 'refresh' to mean UI update. Refreshing data itself is requerying, reloading, refreshing or fetching.

Comment: So in my original example... if I set a filter after the first SELECT and then run a command after the second SELECT, say I create a loop or something.. is the data still filtered? Thank you that is a big one for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216667/discussion-between-gunnerfan420-and-cetin-basoz).